# Data processing to solve the problem of flexible workplace scheduling to give the best processing time and best job scheduling

Tags: python, excel

I have Excel data that I want to solve to solve the problem of flexible workplace scheduling using the `grapheme` algorithm (the problem is as follows. I have a file that contains a number of jobs and a number of machines. Each job has a number of operations. These operations must be performed on a number of machines available at different times. That is, the operations It must be executed on at least one machine only) How do I design the code to address this problem? If the code for it is available, I hope you will give it to me.

I have included an image illustrating the problem.

[image] .

I want you to help me solve the problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.